# using CallibratedClassifierCv to predict_proba Perceptron model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, auc

I need to make a neural netwok with single layer for a classification problem;
So, I'm using Perceptron.
Then, I need to calculate AUC and I need predict_proba
but predict_proba not provide in Perceptron
I search on the internet and I found I can use CallibratedClassifierCv
but I don't sure about it

my question can I use CallibratedClassifierCv with Perceptron to use predict_proba or there another way? I need to calculate AUC

this is my code

```
mean_fpr=np.linspace(0,1,100)
aucs=[]
tprs=[]
cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4)
for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(cv.split(x,y),1 ):
 X_train= x.iloc[train_index]
 y_train= y[train_index]
 X_test= x.iloc[test_index]
 y_test=y[test_index]
 sm=SMOTE()
 x_oversampled,y_oversampled=sm.fit_resample(X_train,y_train)
 model=Perceptron(tol=1e-3)
 model.fit(x_oversampled,y_oversampled)
 clf=CallibratedClassifierCv(model,cv='prefit', method='isotonic")
 clf.fit(x_oversampled.values,y_oversampled.values)
 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
 print(classification_reprot(y_test, y_pred))
 prediction=clf.predict_proba(X_test)
 fpr,tpr,t= roc_curve(y_test, prediction[:,1])
 tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr,fpr,tpr))
 roc_auc=auc(fpr,tpr)
 aucs.append(roc_auc)
 i=i+1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.